# How to get in-app subscription expired date in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I am using "billingclient V6.0.1"

**def version_billing = "6.0.1"
implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:${version_billing}"**

Can able to purchase the subscription but I can't get the end date.

In the documentation they follow the steps but it will through error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.",
        "domain": "androidpublisher",
        "reason": "projectNotLinked"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/get

I don't know why this is so complicated. Please share your points about this Also this type of end date and cancel can be done on back end or app side. Thanks in advance.